# On click and mouse up in same component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a table.I added onMonseUp and onClick in the same component .When a user clicks and drags through the cells, it opens the dialog. But when I onClick in a cell it doesn't open the dialog.
I want to when mouse up it open the dialog and when I click it also open the dialog

Here is my code

```js
export default function Table() {

    const [start, setStart] = useState(null);
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(0);
    const [selecting, setSelecting] = useState(false);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    let toggleModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    let beginSelection = i => {
        setSelecting(true);
        setStart(i);
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let endSelection = (i = end) => {
        setSelecting(false);
        updateSelection(i);
        toggleModal();
    };

    let updateSelection = i => {
        if(selecting) {
            setEnd(i);
        }
    };

    let cells = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < 12*4; j++) {
            cells.push(
                <Cell key={j}
                      inputColor={
                          (end <= j && j <= start || (start <= j && j <= end) ? "#adf": "")
                      }
                      onMouseDown={()=>beginSelection(j)}
                      onMouseUp={()=>endSelection(j)}
                      onMouseMove={()=> updateSelection(j)}
                      onClick={toggleModal}
                >
                    {j+1}
                </Cell>
            )
        }

    return (
        <TableCalendar>
            {cells}
            <Dialog onClose={()=> toggleModal()} show={isOpen} >
                Here's some content for the modal
            </Dialog>
        </TableCalendar>
    )
}
```

Here are my full code and demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Kalipts/ReactMouseEvent

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you could be calling toggleModal twice? onMouseDown calls toggleModal and onClick calls toggleModal. Try removing the onMouseDown and just use the onClick. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click, `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` will be called.  So in your case, `toggleModal` is called twice, in `onMouseUp` and `onClick`.  That is why the variable will be back to it's value.

You can remove `onClick` and just let the `onMouseUp` show the modal so that you will have the correct selection also. You can also directly call `setIsOpen(true)` in onclick.

```
<Cell
  key={j}
  inputColor={
    (end <= j && j <= start) || (start <= j && j <= end) ? "#adf" : ""
  }
  onMouseDown={() => beginSelection(j)}
  onMouseUp={() => endSelection(j)}
  onMouseMove={() => updateSelection(j)}
  onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
>
    {j + 1}
</Cell>
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-spence-58q0o

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `onClick={toggleModal}`. It's redundant to the `toggleModal` from `onMouseUp` via `endSelection`, and doing it twice is the same as not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `toggleModal` function and do `setIsOpen()` directly.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Dialog from "./Modal";

const TableCalendar = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto);
  background-color: #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const Cell = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.inputColor || "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"};
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
`;

export default function Table() {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(null);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState(0);
  const [selecting, setSelecting] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  let beginSelection = i => {
    setSelecting(true);
    setStart(i);
    updateSelection(i);
  };

  let endSelection = (i = end) => {
    setSelecting(false);
    updateSelection(i);
    setIsOpen(true)
  };

  let updateSelection = i => {
    if (selecting) {
      setEnd(i);
    }
  };

  let cells = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 12 * 4; j++) {
    cells.push(
      <Cell
        key={j}
        inputColor={
          (end <= j && j <= start) || (start <= j && j <= end) ? "#adf" : ""
        }
        onMouseDown={() => beginSelection(j)}
        onMouseUp={() => endSelection(j)}
        onMouseMove={() => updateSelection(j)}
        onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      >
        {j + 1}
      </Cell>
    );
  }

  return (
    <TableCalendar>
      {cells}
      <Dialog onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} show={isOpen}>
        Here's some content for the modal
      </Dialog>
    </TableCalendar>
  );
}
```